# woocommerce hook publish product

Tags: plugins

I want to add an action whenever the admin publishes a product, but the WP hook publish_post does not trigger then - even though a wc product is just another type of post.

I haven't found a woocommerce hook that triggers when a product is published.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommand you to use the `transition_post_status`. See example below :

```
 add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse_110037_new_posts', 10, 3);
 function wpse_110037_new_posts($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
 if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
          //add some cde here
     }

  }
```

This hook is really handy. It allows you to target a specific action: every time post data is saved. But with code I add you can avoid trigger your code if it's a draft save or an updtate.

Comment: Any reason you're using `in_array ()` with a single item rather than just `==`?

Comment: @RobinJ yes, in fact you're right but I'd like to do things this way for maintenance purpose. If I want to add another post type to add it will be faster and I don't have to rewrite the line. Most of the time I use classes so in my code this looks like that ```in_array( $post->post_type, $this->allowed_post_types )```

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: i was trying to implement this with some taxonomy terms, but i couldnt get this run, the terms where always empty on `publish`. i got it working on `update` (not with this specific function here, i used another one (but in the end i used this one)), but i wanted it to work on `publish`. i guess, because the terms are not saved, yet. glad i came up with the idea of using `$_POST` variable. its all in there..

Answer (score 1):

If You add a new product in woocommerce then send `product_id`

```
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'my_product_update' );
function my_product_update( $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == "product" ) {
         $productId = $post->ID;
         // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use :

```
add_action( 'publish_product', array($this, 'prd_published_message'), 10, 2);

function prd_published_message( $ID, $post ) {
  ...
}
```

http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wp_transition_post_status/

Comment: Could you post a link referencing this "`publish_product`" action hook? Because I'm not able to find it anywhere... If that would be a real WC hook, it would have a `woocommerce_` prefix...

Comment: Yes you are wright, it works but it's not documented

Comment: @ClemC It's too late but might be helpful to someone. it's {status}_{post_type} Hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions